# Puppet and modules, doesn't it get to be a lot?

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I'm reading the latest puppet book, and it breaks things down into modules which is nice.

In one example, they created a module for SSH, so:

```
/modules/ssh/{files, manifests, ...}
```

Then you can include that module to your node classes.

My question is, for a live production puppet config, this basically means you will have a lot of modules correct?  I mean if you create one for ssh, the list is going to be pretty long wouldn't you say?

```
e.g.:
I need: nginx, ssh, mysql, phusion passenger, etc. etc.
```

Those are the major components, but if I write a module for each service I need, the list I think will get long.

On the other hand, ssh already comes setup with Ubuntu, so maybe the example in the book was a little contrived just to teach the idea behind modules?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it..

You basically have a default node which includes everything all servers should do.. Then you can even have a production node that inherits default and includes everything production servers need. Then you have your node which inherits production in your site.pp

So for example

```
node default {
    include linux
    include ssh::install
}
node prod inherits default {
    include postfix::relay
}
node www.domain.com inherits prod {
    include apache::install
}
```

So my node www.domain.com will include

```
linux
ssh::install
postfix::relay
apache::install
```

Comment: Use composite classes instead of inheriting node.

Answer (score 1):

Well, turn that question on its head. If you *don't* use modules, where are you going to put all your configuration?

Let's take, for example, ssh. Indeed, ssh comes installed on pretty much any modern Unix, however...

- Do you have each server's ssh key on `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_keys`?
- Is your `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_keys` readable by all?

The answer is no on both counts for Ubuntu and no on the first count for any system. The ssh module I use (and which I got from github) takes care of copying each server's key to the known keys of every other server.

Now, to get that, I just need an `include ssh::server`. Isn't that much easier than having the whole configuration on each server?

The other aspect to consider is that a module can include other modules, and so on. And you can have classes and definitions not inside any module also including them.

For example, a typical node of mine has just a few lines like these:

```
include linux-server
include agencia
```

Where `linux-server` has everything that is required of standard linux servers (with lots of conditionals to handle stuff like virtual servers vs physical servers), and `agencia` is a template for one particular application, including configuration for apache, php, drupal, exported configurations for nginx and varnish, etc.